# Data modification between classes C#

Tags: c#

I have a main class and an object which references the main class through constructor. The question is, how can I alter a property from the main class, within the object class?

```
public class First
{
   public int x = 0;
   public Second second;
   public First()
   {
      second = new Second(this);
   }    

   public run()
   {
      second.change();
   }


}
public class Second
{
   private First _first;
   public Second(First first)
   {
       _first = first;
   }

   public change()
   {
      first.x = 2;
   }
}
```

I don't want to use static classes because, First is in fact a DLL which runs inside Protrader, which in turn may run multiple First instances in parallel. Having static classes will leak data between these instances. So, I need to change a variable in the First class, by passing it as a parameter to the constructor of another class. (ref this) doesn't work.
I also tried to create a wrapper class of first.
public First Wrapper;
and within First constructor instantiate Wrapper = this.. and then second = new Second(ref Wrapper). That compiled, but, didn't work either.

The purpose of this exercice is because I had a huge First class which compiles to a single DLL. Protrader will load a single DLL and runs it in paralell on different instruments at the same time (dolar, iene, euro , etc). If I use static methods the state control variables will "leak" to other instruments and that will ruin the logic.

These First class already have 2000 lines, and keeps growing. I decided to modularize it. Export some methods that it currently has to specializes classes such as log, events, trading commands, etc. But, these classes alter properties within each other and within the main class.

Comment: Can you show us how you're calling this in main? I'm not clear as to what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a function to modify the property?

Comment: Also, don't have public fields. Properties should be used instead.

Comment: Are you attempting to reflect the changes across all instances of `First` no matter where the reference is? So if I have `First f1` and `First f2` and make my change in `Second`, then `f1` and `f2` both reflect that change?

Comment: What matters is, inside First, at any point, I will call run().. and then, run will call second.change() which in turn should alter the property x in First.

Comment: The purpose of a Second class is because I had a huge First class, and then I exported some of its methods to a Second Class , but, these exported methods also alters properties from First Class. Hence.. I need data persistence between classes without using static methods, and also, I want to be able to change properties from First Class inside any other classes that I will instantiate.. I can for instance create a Third third = new Third(this).. and Third has another method which in turn alters some property from First.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Looks like the code was right from the start. I was not able to run my DLL because of another problem. Thank you all for the help provided!

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just make a function inside the First class that can modify the variable?

Like so:

```
public class First
{
   public int x = 0;
   public Second second;
   public First()
   {
      second = new Second(this);
   }    

   public run()
   {
      second.change();
   }

   public modifyX(int changedX)
   {
       x = changedX
   }

}
public class Second
{
   private First _first;
   public Second(First first)
   {
       _first = first;
   }

   public change()
   {
      _first.modifyX(2);
   }
}
```

Comment: This will only impact the value of `x` in `Second`'s instance of `First`; in which case you just make `x` a property.

Comment: The purpose of a Second class is because I had a huge class, and then I exported some of its methods to a Second Class , but, these exported methods also alters properties from First Class. Hence.. I need data persistence between classes without using static methods, and also, I want to be able to change properties from First inside any other classes..

Answer (score 0):

The property x in class First could also be written as

```
private int _x;
public int x
{
    get { return _x; }
    set { _x = value; }
}
```

Made some minor changes to the code you provided, hope it helps

```
public class First
{
    public int x { get; set; }

    public Second second;
    public First()
    {
        x = 0;
        second = new Second(this);
    }    

    public void run()
    {
        second.change();
    }


}
public class Second
{
    private First _first;
    public Second(First first)
    {
        _first = first;
    }

    public void change()
    {
        _first.x = 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a globally reflected change though; you'll only be impacting `Second`'s reference to `First`.